# How to add more constructors in Greeting class for Guestbook example(GAE)

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

I want to create one more constructor 'content2' in the Greeting class but cannot run the app using google app engine. 
I really cannot spot the problem. help!

Besides, I dont know why this code use

```
greetings = Greeting.query(
        ancestor=guestbook_key(guestbook_name)) \
        .order(-Greeting.date) \
        .fetch(10)
```

instead of

```
query = ndb.gql("SELECT * "
                        "FROM Greetings "
                       "WHERE ANCESTOR IS :1 "
                        "ORDER BY date DESC",
                         guest_name)
```

This is guestbook.py

```
import urllib
import webapp2
import jinja2
import os
import datetime
import cgi


from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.api import images
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app


JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/templates"),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],
    autoescape=True)

DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME = 'default_guestbook'
    def guestbook_key(guestbook_name=DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME):
    return ndb.Key('Guestbook', guestbook_name)


class Author(ndb.Model):
    """Sub model for representing an author."""
    identity = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)


class Greeting(ndb.Model):
    """A main model for representing an individual Guestbook entry."""
    author = ndb.StructuredProperty(Author)
    content = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    content2 = ndb.TextProperty(indexed=False)
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)


    class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        guestbook_name = self.request.get('guestbook_name',
                                      DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME)
        greetings = Greeting.query(
            ancestor=guestbook_key(guestbook_name)) \
            .order(-Greeting.date) \
            .fetch(10)

        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'Logout'
        else:
            url = users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)
            url_linktext = 'Login'

    template_values = {
        'user': user,
        'greetings': greetings,
        'guestbook_name': urllib.quote_plus(guestbook_name),
        'url': url,
        'url_linktext': url_linktext,
    }

    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')
    self.response.write(template.render(template_values))

class Guestbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        guestbook_name = self.request.get('guestbook_name',
                                      DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME)
        greeting = Greeting(parent=guestbook_key(guestbook_name))

    if users.get_current_user():
        greeting.author = Author(
                identity=users.get_current_user().user_id(),
                email=users.get_current_user().email())

    greeting.content = self.request.get('content')
    greeting.content2 = self.request.get('content2')
    greeting.put()

    query_params = {'guestbook_name': guestbook_name}
    self.redirect('/?' + urllib.urlencode(query_params))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/sign', Guestbook),

], debug=True)
```

This is index.html

```
....
 <form action="/sign?guestbook_name={{ guestbook_name }}" method="post">
  <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
   <div class="desc2">
   Image of cat url: 
   <div><textarea name="content2" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
   <div class="desc2">
   </div>
  <div><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
  </form>
 {% for greeting in greetings %}
<!----------------------------------------------------------->
  {% if greeting.author %}
    <b>{{ greeting.author.email }}
      {% if user and user.user_id() == greeting.author.identity %}
        (You)
      {% endif %}
    </b> wrote:
  {% else %}
   An anonymous person wrote:
  {% endif %}
 <!----------------------------------------------------------->

    <blockquote> {{greeting.content2}}

 <!----------------------------------------------------------->
  {{ greeting.content }}</blockquote>
{% endfor %}

....
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific about the current undesired behavior?

Comment: Instead of having only 3 constructors in the Greeting class, I want to have one more constructor. Thus, I added    'content2 = ndb.TextProperty(indexed=False)' in the Greeting class and 'greeting.content2 = self.request.get('content2')' in the Guestbook class. But the code does not seem to be working.

Comment: "does not seem to be working" is vague.... why doesn't it work? is it an error, is it not what you expect?

Comment: nothing appears on the webpage, so I suppose the code is not compilable...

Comment: You should have something in the logs of your console then?

Comment: Your use of the term 'constructor' is somewhat confusing. What you are referring to is the NDB Model property 'content2'; the constructor method can instantiate a Model class with that property (if desired).